# in my jsp code i got a null pointer exception error i am using net beans software. how to clear that exception?

Tags: jsp

in my jsp code i got a null pointer exception error i am using net beans software. how to clear that exception?

this is my code

```
<%
    Connection  conn=null;  

    try 
    {   Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");             
                 conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Mimi", "", "");  
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {   out.println(exc.toString() + "<br>");  }

    out.println ("Database Connected.");
    conn.close ( );
    out.println ("Database closed.");
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for the possibility that the Connection object might be null.

```
if (conn != null )
    conn.close();
```

This may not be the null pointer exception you are seeing, but without a stack trace, it is impossible to be sure.